# Is there a way to down cast an enum rawValue to its type?

Tags: swift, enums

I have the following enum:

```
enum Difficulty: Int {
    case Opt1 = 1, Opt2 = 2, Opt3 = 3    
}
```

When I try to use it as an Int like that: `MyClass.Difficulty.Opt1.rawValue` it doesn't allow me, because it returns a RawValue.
Shouldn't it be smart to understand that this is an Int?

Comment: I have no troubles getting `rawValue` with your code in playground.

Comment: That's embarrassing. The problem was the function to which I was sending this value. Thanks for your time to test it though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your code I assume that you have an enum nested inside a class like so:

```
class MyClass {
    enum Difficulty: Int {
        case Opt1 = 1, Opt2 = 2, Opt3 = 3
    }
}

var myInteger = MyClass.Difficulty.Opt2.rawValue // Int inferred correctly
```

I'm not finding any problems with this or any variants I can think of. Please post your code for the MyClass type if you are still encountering problems.

Comment: That was not actually the problem, I shouldn't have asked that. I'll accept your answer for posting a clear example anyways

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass it to a function:

```
func someFunction(difficulty: MyClass.Difficulty) {
    let number = difficulty.rawValue 
}

someFunction(.Opt1)
```

or

```
fun someFunction(difficulty: Int) {
    let number = difficulty
}

someFunction(MyClass.Difficulty.Opt1.rawValue)
```