# How to display value of enum

Tags: swift, enums

When using associated values, how do you display the associated value of an enum?

```
enum dayOfWeek{
    case Monday(String)
    case Tuesday(String)
    case Wednesday(String)
}
```

The following fails:

```
var someDay = dayOfWeek.Wednesday("Wednesday-4")
println(someDay.rawValue)
```

Also, is there a way to initialize the enum during its creation using associated values?  For example:

```
enum dayOfWeek{
    case Monday(String: "Monday-2")
    case Tuesday(String: "Tuesday-3")
    case Wednesday(String: "Wednesday-4")
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to down cast an enum rawValue to its type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30010834/is-there-a-way-to-down-cast-an-enum-rawvalue-to-its-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be confusing raw values with associated values. You can think of an enum case's raw value as the underlying value that the case represents. If that's what you want, you'd specify it like this:

```
enum DayOfWeek : String {
    case Monday = "Monday"
    case Tuesday = "Tuesday"
    case Wednesday = "Wednesday"
    // ...
}
```

`String` is the raw value type, and `"Monday"`, `"Tuesday"`, etc. are the raw values, which can be accessed like this:

```
let day = DayOfWeek.Monday
println(day.rawValue)  // "Monday"
```

Associated values, on the other hand, are additional values that are associated with a *particular instance* of an enum case. The code in the question uses associated values, so you'd be specifying a value when you create each particular instance:

```
enum DayOfWeek {
    case Monday(String)
    case Tuesday(String)
    case Wednesday(String)
    // ...
}

let day = DayOfWeek.Monday("The worst")
```

However, you can't extract that value without a `switch` statement:

```
switch day {
case .Monday(let description):
    println(description)
default:
    break
}
```

Comment: It doesn't print "Monday".  It prints "Enum Value".  Is there a way to print out the actual value?

Comment: 6.3.1.  I'm also in the Playground.  If you do println(DayOfWeek.Monday.rawValue), nothing will show in the playground.

Comment: You need to open the assistance editior to see console output.

Comment: Some weirdness in the playground was causing these to not display. Works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

```
enum dayOfWeek: String{
    case Monday = "Monday-2", Tuesday = "Tuesday-3"
}

OtherDay.Monday.rawValue
```

`dayOfWeek` is a enum, you have the enum’s `Monday` and `Tuesday`, the associated value of `Monday` has been set to `"Monday-2"`. To get this value you could use the `.rawValue` of the enum

Comment: How are you assigning OtherDay?  Also, how do you println the rawValue?  I keep getting "Enum Value".